# Problem with CMake finding my header file

Tags: c++, cmake

So I am trying to compile a small project that I am doing of a Sokoban Solver. For that, I have the following folder structure:
[image: File structure]

The CMakeLists file that I have generated is quite simple and contains the following lines of code:

```
project(Sokoban)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

include_directories(include/)
add_executable(main src/main.cpp src/coord.cpp src/map.cpp src/node_data.cpp src/node.cpp src/search_methods.cpp)
```

As I understand it:

- Executable needs to have the *.cpp files
- The directory with the *.hpp files must be included somehow to the CMake so the compiler knows where to look for them.

When I try to compile, I obtain the following error:

```
[build] ../src/main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: include/search_methods.hpp: No such file or directory
[build]     4 | #include "include/search_methods.hpp"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
```

Does anyone know how or which other information would you need to solve this issue? I have been looking into similar problems, but did not solve the issue.

Comment: Either drop the `include` folder from your `#include` statements or from your include path; can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

As @tkausl pointed out

```
Either drop the include folder from your #include statements or from your include path; can't have both.
```

Change `#include "include/search_methods.hpp"` to  `#include "search_methods.hpp"` and it should work.

Also consider to use a more modern CMake approach using

```
target_include_directories(main
    PUBLIC
        include
)
```

and git rid of `include_directories(include/)`